# Junit test case for WebClient Builder for spring framework for reactive

Tags: mockito, junit5, powermockito, spring-boot-test, spring-framework-beans

Code for Get call using web client which I am trying to unit test

```
webClient.get().uri("http://localhost:8080/employee/{id}", xyz).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work

```
doReturn(requestHeadersUriMock).when(webClientMock).get();
doReturn(requestHeadersMock).when(requestHeadersUriMock)
        .uri(anyString());
doReturn(responseMock).when(requestHeadersMock).retrieve();
doReturn(Mono.just(....)).when(responseMock).bodyToMono(String.class);

//Assertions
```

Comment: Its not working

Comment: @GauravKhandelwal May be help with what you have tried instead of just giving one line in the question. The above snippet is from a working code where you have to mock and give the correct response/mocks based on the use case.